# Getting the "Duchess" font to work

Tags: fonts

I downloaded some TTF fonts from Fontpalace to my web page at zackel.com/fonts/ and then I use @font to access them. This works fine for the "Constitution" font, and every other font I've tried - except for "Duchess" , as you can see in this jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mzvswy4e/4/.  I've tried copying the Duchess ttf file from other sources besides Fontpalace to my font/ directory but the results are always the same: it doesn't work.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Thanks.

```
@font-face {
    font-family:constitution;   
    src: url(https://zackel.com/fonts/Constitution.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family:duchess;    
    src: url(https://zackel.com/fonts/Duchess.ttf);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer: the following is experimental work based on a sample size of 2 right now, but is corroborated by https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/issues/121 : Unicode cmap seems to be required for some applications.)

I've looked at both fonts with [`ttfdump`](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/tools/tools.aspx), and Duchess.ttf has only two encodings in the file:

> ### 'cmap' Table - Character to Glyph Index Mapping Table
>
> ```
>      'cmap' version: 0
>      number of encodings: 2
>      number of subtables: 2
> ```
>
> Encoding   0.    PlatformID:  1
>                    EcodingID:   0
>                    SubTable: 0, Offset: 0x00000014
>
> Encoding   1.    PlatformID:  3
>                    EcodingID:   1
>                    SubTable: 1, Offset: 0x0000011a

[The specs](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/name.htm#plat) suggest that's for Mac (Id 1) and Windows (Id 3, Encoding 1 is Unicode Basic Plane, UCS-2), while the working font has three:

> ### 'cmap' Table - Character to Glyph Index Mapping Table
>
> ```
>      'cmap' version: 0
>      number of encodings: 3
>      number of subtables: 2
> ```
>
> Encoding   0.    PlatformID:  0
>                    EcodingID:   0
>                    SubTable: 0, Offset: 0x00000124
>
> Encoding   1.    PlatformID:  1
>                    EcodingID:   0
>                    SubTable: 1, Offset: 0x0000001c
>
> Encoding   2.    PlatformID:  3
>                    EcodingID:   1
>                    SubTable: 0, Offset: 0x00000124

The extra one is Unicode 1.0. Note how the offset is the same as for the Windows encoding, because it's both basically the same Unicode. My wild guess is that browsers will want the Unicode encoding. I would assume that a tool like [FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) can add it, since it's just another pointer at the table you already have.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ulrich. I'm not a font guy, though, and I'm a little unsure how to proceed with the information you provided. If you have the time and you can get duchess working in my  jsFiddle I'd be happy to give you 50 bonus points -  if that means anything to you. Thanks.

Comment: @Steve: I can confirm that just opening the font in FontForge and then hitting `File, Generate Font`, ignoring the error that crops up, appears to fix the font. The resulting file is smaller than the original though, so something else seems to be happening there. Unfortunately, I don't think giving you the modified file would be covered by the academic exemptions in copyright law that I need to claim to modify the font in the first place. But as I said, it's three clicks, and Fontforge is precompiled for Windows and Mac, so I hope it's not too much hassle for you.

Comment: I copied Duchess.ttf to Duchess5.ttf and then did the FontForge generate on it.  But it's not clear where the modified file is going.  The timestamp on Duchess5.ttf is exactly the same before and after the generate, so it's not going over the old file.  I see that a pfb file is being generated, but I'm not sure what to do with it.

Comment: @Steve: These settings worked for me: TrueType, No Bitmap Fonts (only choice for TrueType), Options: TrueType Hints, PS Glyph Names, OpenType, No Rename.